# Selecting elements from a list with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

Pretty general question here, let me know if you would like me to elaborate more.  I have a list of elements, each rendered by a view.  When an element is clicked, it is highlighted, and the view responsible for that element sends its model to a separate view which displays additional information related to that element.

I'm trying to implement functionality for a user to use the arrow keys to switch between elements, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is the code for my View:

```
var app = app || {};

app.EmployeeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'list-group-item',
    template: _.template('<%= Name %>'),
    render: function() {
    var html = this.template(this.model.attributes);
    this.$el.html(html);
},
events: {
    "mouseover" : function() {
        this.$el.addClass('highlighted');

    },
    "mouseout" : function() {
        this.$el.removeClass('highlighted');
    },
    "click" : function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        this.$el.addClass('selected');
        $(document).trigger('select', [this.model]);
    },
},
});
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can implement using arrow keys to trigger the appropriate view to forward its model?

Comment: Please, show your container of EmployeeView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar feature to implement for my product. I have a list of images. The user clicks on one thumbnail and visualize the image full size. There, I also have a detail box showing info of the picture, and I wanted the user to use arrow keys to got through the pics while staying in the full size view. I also have "prev" and "next" buttons that should work the same. I think the result is clean and this is what I did:

```
SingleEntryView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function() {

        // Here I save a reference to the currentIndex by getting the index
        // of the current model within the collection.
        this.currentIndex = this.collection.indexOf(this.model);

        // Important: here I attach the keydown event to the whole document,
        // so that the user doesn't necessarily have to focus the view's
        // element to use the arrows.
        $document.on('keydown.singleEntry', this.onKeyDown.bind(this));

    },

    // Having attached the keydown event to document, there's no autocleaning.
    // Overriding remove to detach the listener when the view goes away.
    remove : function() {

        $document.off('.singleEntry');

        Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);

    },

    // Keydown listener. Interested only in arrow keys.
    onKeyDown : function(e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 37) // left arrow
            this.prev();
        else if (e.keyCode == 39) // right arrow
            this.next();

        return true;

    },

    // Click events on the prev/next buttons (they behave == to the arrow keys)
    events : {
        'click #prev' : 'prev',
        'click #next' : 'next'
    },

    // Handlers shared by both prev/next buttons and arrow keys.
    // What is the current index? Go to the prev/next one.
    // If we are at the start/end, wrap around and go to the last/first.
    prev : function() {
        this.goTo(this.currentIndex > 0 ? this.currentIndex - 1 : this.collection.length - 1);
        return false;
    },

    next : function() {
        this.goTo(this.currentIndex < this.collection.length - 1 ? this.currentIndex + 1 : 0);
        return false;
    },

    goTo : function(i) {

        this.model = this.collection.at(i);
        this.currentIndex = i;

        // App is my Router
        App.navigate('app/boards/' + this.collection.id + '/entries/' + this.model.id, {
            trigger: true
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better answer. I didn't consider using my router to retrieve the next model in the series.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Eheh, to be completely honest, I've made it simpler for the purpose of this question, but in production I use a slightly different approach that will just describe here. As you noticed, I call the router with `trigger: true` to trigger the re-rendeting of the view with the new model. It's fine. But to optimize it a bit, you could call it with `replace: true` instead, that will only replace the url in the browser but won't trigger rerendering. You have to render the "new" pieces yourself (eg, I fill the "detail" box with plain jQuery selectors), but of course this would be super optimized!