# Pattern for caching a View's sub-elements in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Moving from a framework-less world to Backbone.js, I've brought along the practice of "caching" my jQuery objects by always storing a reference to them (for efficiency).

```
var myCachedEl = $('#element');
myCachedEl.on('click', function() {
  myCachedEl.html('That tickles.');
});
```

In Backbone, this is how I might cache my jQuery objects:

```
var RandomView = Backbone.View.extend({

  intitialize: function() {
    this.$lastRoll = this.$el.find('#last-roll');
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$lastRoll.html(this.model.get('lastRoll'));
  },

  events: {
    'click #last-roll': function() {
      this.model.roll();
    }
  }
});

var randomView = new RandomView({
  el: '#random-view',
  model: random
});
```

Given my *current* setup, I would like to do something *akin* to...

```
events: {
    'click this.$lastRoll': function() {
      // ...
    }
}
```

...where, in my events, I could bind a click event to a cached element. However, the above syntax does not work. I suspect there *may* be some way to "officially" define sub-elements, so that I *could* use some syntax akin to what is above.

**Question:** Is there a "better," "cleaner," or more "Backbone-semantic" pattern, for caching my View's sub-elements, that I could/should follow, instead of my current pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are caching your elements correctly. Simply, the syntax to bind event handlers doesn't work the way you propose in your question. Because it works in a different way.

All the events that you define with `events: { ... }` are bound to the the view's root element `el`, and not to the child element `last-roll`. When an event fires within your view, it will bubble up to the root element, and there the handler will decide if the `target` of the event matches the selector. For example, in your code:

```
events: {
    'click #last-roll': function...
}
```

binds a click event to `RandomView`, and when a click occurs, it will check if the target is `last-roll` (ie, matches the selector) and if this is true your handler will be invoked. That's why you pass selectors and not elements there. It's efficient, so go for it.

If you still need to bind events to other elements (such as `document` for [global keypress event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221535/selecting-elements-from-a-list-with-backbone-js/18228489#18228489) or the likes) you can use jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or Backbone's [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo). With `on` you have to remember to deregister your handlers by using [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) when removing your view to prevent memory leaks, while with `listenTo` you can rely on the automatic cleanup made by Backbone itself.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of how the bubbling works. It sounds like I don't have anything to really worry about in terms of performance; I had imagined that, internally, Backbone was $(selecting) elements and calling .on() to each one, like I had in the past. How vain of me to assume the Backbone devs were following the same awful habits I had. :P